# How to see if an element is visible in screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a `XAML` page and I want to know if an element is visible for user on screen or not.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Can you see me?"/>
</StackPanel>
```

here I want if that `StackPanel` or `TextBlock` is visible, I change it's color. Is it possible?

*(It's a Windows Phone app)*

Comment: Hi @makc . I don't mean `Visible` or `Collapsed`.. think of a long page, an element can be at the bottom of the page and not visible to the user, so if he scroll can see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the coordinates of the `StackPanel` relative to the layout root. If it's beyond the screen borders, then it isn't displayed:

```
stackPanel.TransformToVisual(layoutRoot).Transform(new Point())
```

Note this will not work for controls in virtualized `ItemsControl`s.